# Checking if UNIX timestamp is within a UNIX range

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Users on my site have the ability to request a session with another user. They enter time from that they like and time to that they like. I then convert both of these values into a UNIX timestamp.

The user that they want a session with has their availability stored in the database in UNIX format as time_from and time_to.

I need to make a query to check to make sure that the value they enter is within the availability range.

Let's do an example. Let's say that the first user's availability is from 1360764000 to 1360767600 (2:00 PM to 3:00 PM February 13th, 2013) and the second user requests a session from 1360764000 to 1360765800 (2:00 PM to 2:30PM February 13th 2013).

How can I make sure that the values entered are within that range?

Comment: Is this a PHP question, or an SQL question? If the latter, what's the database?

Comment: It's a PHP question. Thanks for looking :)

Comment: then your just looking if a number falls between 2 other numbers, cant you at least try and code that

Answer (score 0):

Since a unix timestamp is essentially an integer something like

```
where time_from <= entered_from_time AND time_to >= entered_to_time
```